# NSPredicate example of one to many relationship query

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode9

[This is my core data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a45lh.png)

The relationship is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vneZq.png)

The relationship is one Route to many Locations. First question is should there be a name attribute (routeName) in Location? In DB2 for example, you always name your primary keys, but most examples I have seen in Core Data they handle primary keys under the covers in the relationship definition.

Here are Table excerpts from DB Browser for sqlite.

[Table Excerpts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyLzs.png)

Here is the code:

```
    final class CoreDataManager {

static let sharedInstances = CoreDataManager()

let managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext

private init(){
    let application = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    managedContext = application.persistentContainer.viewContext
}


func createRoute(name: String) -> Route {
    let routeEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Route", in: managedContext)!
    let route = NSManagedObject(entity: routeEntity, insertInto: managedContext)

    route.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "name")

    route.setValue(Date().timeIntervalSince1970, forKey: "ts")

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    return route as! Route
}

func createLocation(loc: CLLocation, route: Route) {

    let locationEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Location", in: managedContext)!
    let location = NSManagedObject(entity: locationEntity, insertInto: managedContext)

    location.setValue(loc.coordinate.latitude, forKeyPath: "latitude")
    location.setValue(loc.coordinate.longitude, forKeyPath: "longitude")
    location.setValue(loc.altitude, forKeyPath: "altitude")
    location.setValue(loc.timestamp, forKeyPath: "ts")
    location.setValue(route, forKeyPath: "route")

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}

func getAllRoutes () -> [Route] {
    let routeFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Route")
    let routeResults = try! managedContext.fetch(routeFetch)
    return routeResults as! [Route]
}

func getLocationsByRoute (name: String) -> [Location] {
    let locFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Location")

    //select * from ZLOCATION, ZROUTE where ZLOCATION.ZROUTE = ZROUTE.Z_PK and ZROUTE.ZNAME = ?
    locFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "locations.route = %@", name)
    locFetch.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "ts", ascending: false)]

    let locations = try! managedContext.fetch(locFetch)

    return locations as! [Location]
}
```

}

If no primary key in Location Table, how do I create a query to get all Locations for a given Route? You can see in the code I have a getLocationsByRoute method, but cannot get the query to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

- If you have the `Route` object, get the locations from the `locations` property
- If you have to fetch the objects use the predicate format

  ```
  locFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "route.name = %@", name)
  ```

  The key path is always `<relationship name>.<attribute name>` – in this case get all `Location` objects whose `name` of the related `route` is equal to the given name.

Answer (score 0):

Stop thinking in database terms, Core Data is an ORM.

You get all locations for a route by accessing the `locations` property of the `Route` class since it corresponds to the one to many relationship between `Route` and `Location`

```
let locations = someRoute.locations
```

Comment: This syntax has always confused me. So you are saying if I get the Route Object from Core Data, I can just reference the object.locations to get an array of Location objects? In my case, all I had was a route name, and was trying to get all the locations for that related route. So instead, you are saying to get the route object (which I don't really need, as I just need the locations). Let me give that a shot. Appreciate you and Vadian's help